# I get an error when setting data for MUI's DatePicker

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

I have a string "2023-04-20", when I assign a value to a DatePicker I get an error: The above error occurs in the <ForwardRef(DesktopDatePicker2)> component:

value= "2023-04-20"

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DatePicker format='YYYY-MM-DD' value={value} />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I tried changing the string "2023-04-20" to Date format but still getting this erro